# Erro simples no código em Haskell

Tags: haskell

Estou iniciando no WinHugs, programando em Haskell. Sou novo em Programaçao Funcional. Desde ontem estou procurando solucionar o erro que tem no código abaixo mas sem êxito até o momento. Segue o código:

```
eq2grau::(Int->Int->Int)->Int 
eq2grau (a1, b1, c1) =
    if(delt1 (a1, b1, c1) > 0 ){
        then (((-b1) + sqrt(delt1(a1 b1 c1))) / (2 * a1))
        then (((-b1) - sqrt(delt1(a1 b1 c1))) / (2 * a1))
        }else
            if((delt1 (a1 b1 c1) == 0 ))
                then ((-b1)/(2 * a1))
                    else a1


delt1::Int->Int->Int->Int
delt1 ah be ce = 
            if(be > 0)
                then ((be * be) - (4 * ah *ce))
                    else ((be * be) - (4 * ah *ce))
```

[image: Esse é o erro!]

Comment: Não programo em Haskell, mas me parece que há dois erros em seu código, pelo que vi em um [exemplo](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Control_structures): 1. Você não deve colocar as condições do `if` dentro de parênteses. 2. Você deve alinhar o `else` ao `then`, ou seja, colocá-los com a mesma indentação.

Answer (score 4):

Tem um monte de erros no seu código mas a boa notícia é que a maioria deles é só erro de sintaxe, que é fácil de resolver :)

### Sintaxe de declaração de tipos

A declaração de tipos diz que `eq2grau` recebe um único argumento (que é uma função maluca) e retorna um `Int`. A versão certa recebe os três argumentos separados.

```hs
eq2grau :: (Int->Int->Int)->Int       -- errado
eq2grau :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -- certo
```

Você também não precisa de vírgula na declaração dos argumentos. A versão que você escreveu recebe um único argumento (que é uma tupla) ao invés de 3 argumentos separados.

```hs
-- errado
eq2grau (a1, b1, c1) = ...

-- certo
eq2grau a1 b1 c1 =  ...
```

### Sintaxe de chamada de função

Em Haskell a sintaxe de chamada de função é só na base do espaço mesmo, e não precisa de vírgula. Os parênteses vão envolta da chamada inteira ou de parâmetros individuais ao invés de ir em volta da lista de parâmetros.

```hs
-- Nesses casos passamos 2 argumentos para f:
f x y
(f x y)
f x (y+z)

-- Já nesses outros casos, f só recebe 1 argumento
f(x,y)  -- f recebe uma tupla como argumento
f(x y)  -- x é uma função e f recebe o valor x aplicado em y.
```

No seu caso...

```hs
delt1 (a1, b1, c1) > 0  -- errado
delt1 (a1  b1  c1) > 0  -- errado 

(delt a1 b1 c2)    > 0  -- certo
delt a1 b1 c1      > 0  -- também certo
```

### Chaves no `if`

Haskell não usa chaves `{}` como em C

```hs
if( ... ){                -- errado
if ... then ... else ...  -- certo
```

Em Haskell o normal é agrupar as coisas via identação, que nem em Python (tome cuidado pra não misturar tabs com espaços, btw)

```hs
if x > y then
    "Hello world"
else
    "Goodbye world"
```

Repare que não precisa de parênteses em volta do condicional. Também não precisa de por um `return` em cada ramo. O `if` do Haskell já é uma expressão com um valor, similar ao operador ternário de C, o `?:`.

### Retorno de múltiplos valores

Meio esquisito esse `if` com 2 `then` né?

```hs
-- errado
then (((-b1) + sqrt(delt1(a1 b1 c1))) / (2 * a1))
then (((-b1) - sqrt(delt1(a1 b1 c1))) / (2 * a1))
```

Não sei como você esperava que iria funcionar :) O normal em Haskell (ou qualquer outra linguagem, pra falar a verdade) seria retornar uma lista de respostas.

```hs
-- Precisa mudar o tipo da sua função pra dizer que retorna uma lista...
eq2grau::(Int->Int->Int)-> [Int]

-- .. e mudar os ifs.
if delt1 (a1, b1, c1) > 0 then
    -- Determinante positivo, duas soluções:
    [ ((-b1) + sqrt(delt1 a1 b1 c1)) / (2 * a1),
      ((-b1) - sqrt(delt1 a1 b1 c1)) / (2 * a1) ]
else if delt1 (a1, b1, c1) == 0
    -- Determinante zero, uma solução só:
    [ ((-b1)/(2 * a1)) ]
else
    -- Determinante negativo, nenhuma solução:
    [ ]
```

### `if` redundante

A identação desse `if` tá esquisita.

```hs
delt1 :: Int->Int->Int->Int
delt1 ah be ce = 
    if  be > 0
      then ((be * be) - (4 * ah *ce))
            else ((be * be) - (4 * ah *ce))
```

O normal seria

```hs
delt1 ah be ce = 
    if be > 0 then
        ((be * be) - (4 * ah *ce))
    else
        ((be * be) - (4 * ah *ce))
```

Além disso, os dois ramos do if são iguais. Nem precisava do if!

```hs
delt1 ah be ce = 
   (be * be) - (4 * ah *ce)
```

### Equação de 2o grau com inteiros?

Vai dar um erro de tipo quando você tentar tirar a raiz quadrada de um número inteiro. Porque não usar números de ponto flutuante para tudo?

```hs
eq2grau :: Double -> Double > Double -> [Double]
delt1 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
```

### Conta da determinante aparece mais de uma vez

Isso é mais uma sugestão de estilo mas porque não usar um `let` pra evitar de calcular o determinandte mais de uma vez? Programar na base do ctrl-c-ctrl-v é indesejável em qualquer linguagem de programação :)

```hs
let d = delt1 a1 b1 c1 in
```

### Resumindo tudo

A versão com todas as correções fica assim. Testei e funcionou

```hs
eq2grau :: Double -> Double -> Double -> [Double]
eq2grau a1 b1 c1 =
  let d = delt1 a1 b1 c1
  if d > 0 then
    [ ((-b1) + sqrt d) / (2 * a1),
      ((-b1) - sqrt d) / (2 * a1)]
  else if d == 0 then
    [ (-b1)/(2 * a1) ]
  else
    []

delt1 :: Double -> Double -> Double -> Double
delt1 ah be ce =
  (be * be) - (4 * ah *ce)
```